# How does @withViewPort decorator work in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was reading this decorators and fount the @withViewPort usage as :

```
import React from 'react';
import withViewport from 'react-decorators/withViewport';

@withViewport
class MyComponent {
  render() {
    let { width, height } = this.props.viewport;
    return <div>Viewport: {width + 'x' + height}</div>;
  }
}

React.render(<MyComponent />, document.body);
```

How does this work @withViewPort decorator work? Does it have state and these state changes while resizing the window size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a higher order component that adds a handler listening to window.resize to your component. Src: https://github.com/kriasoft/react-decorators/blob/master/src/withViewport.js

The decorator is the same as doing:

```
const MyComposedComponent = withComponent(MyComponent);
render(<MyComposedComponent />, document.body);
```